# Using Ansible to list only available NICs from a pool of 10 NICs in Azure

Tags: json, azure, ansible

**Problem statement**:
List only available NICs (not attached to any VM) from a pool of 10 NICs in Azure cloud.

**Condition**:
Not to use Azure resource tags to get NIC state information (is available or not).

Below code snippet solves the problem using tags which fails to satisfy the above condition.

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Get available NICs from NIC Pool
    azure_rm_networkinterface_facts:
      resource_group: '{{NIC_rg_name}}'
      tags:
        - available:yes
    register: NicDetails

  - name: List available NICs
    debug:
      msg: '{{NicDetails.ansible_facts.azure_networkinterfaces}}'
```

How can I achieve the same result without using Azure ressource tags ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe , below code would return all the network interfaces within a resource group

```
- name: Get network interfaces within a resource group
  azure_rm_networkinterface_facts:
    resource_group: Testing
```

This should do what you are looking for.

Also if we want to use tags , we can use the below code

```
- name: Get network interfaces by tag
  azure_rm_networkinterface_facts:
    resource_group: Testing
    tags:
      - testing
      - foo:bar
```

You can find the common return value details [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html#common-return-values).

**Prerequisite to run the module:**

python >= 2.7

azure >= 2.0.0

Comment: The condition is not using 'tags'  to find a solution.